# changing the x value of an image on xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

after looking on the internet for aprox. 1/2 hour 
i have come with.

```
 -(IBAction)left
{
    img.center.x = img.center.x floatValue]-30;
}
```

in an ideal world this would:
when the button is clicked it moves the image 30 pixels to the left

however we do not live in an ideal world and so when I hit build and run it comes up with 2 errors...

> error: cannot convert to a pointer type
>   error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

any soulution or insight into the problem would be greatly recieved.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a typo, you may simply do

```
img.frame = CGRectOffset(img.frame, dx, 0);
```

where `dx` is the value by which to move the x-coordinate of the image.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. It sets your images center point, keeping the y value the same and x value moves 30 points left.

```
img.center =CGPointMake(img.center.x-30, img.center.y);
```

Very simple stuff!